# Setting up Question2Answer on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, question2answer

I have WAMP server installed in my PC.

Apache Version :  2.2.17
PHP Version :  5.3.5
MySQL Version :  5.5.8

Now i want to deploy the Question2Answer on this wamp.
http://www.question2answer.org/install.php

I have done the follows-
1)

```
CREATE USER 'masterqa'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '***';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'masterqa'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '***' WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `masterqa` ;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `masterqa` . * TO 'masterqa'@'localhost';
```

2)

Extracted the zip

qa-config-example.php in the unzipped question2answer folder, and renamed it to qa-config.php

Changed the following

```
define('QA_MYSQL_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1'); // try '127.0.0.1' or 'localhost' if MySQL on same server
    define('QA_MYSQL_USERNAME', 'masterqa');
    define('QA_MYSQL_PASSWORD', 'open');
    define('QA_MYSQL_DATABASE', 'masterqa');
```

3) 
copied the entire folder "question2answer" to the

```
C:\wamp\www
```

but when i try

```
http://localhost/question2answer
```

on my browser it shows some error like

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the same problem. 
I have just deleted the .htaccess file and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

try using the following:

```
define('QA_MYSQL_USERNAME', 'masterqa@localhost');
```

Or

```
flush privileges;
```

**Edit**
I use the following:

1. Download the Project
2. Unzip the Project to my www directory
3. Find qa-config-example.php file
4. Rename the file as qa-config.php
5. Open qa-config.php file in notepad
6. My Settings in qa-config.php file is as follows:
    `define('QA_MYSQL_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1');

    define('QA_MYSQL_USERNAME', 'root');

    define('QA_MYSQL_PASSWORD', '');

    define('QA_MYSQL_DATABASE', 'qa');`
7. Open phpMyAdmin
8. create a database named **qa**
9. Run the project from `localhost`

Comment: @shababhsiddique flush privileges; will work. I just installed this on my system and worked fine.

Comment: Still getting the same problem.. Can you post a stp by stp instruction what you did to set the Question2Answer up?